# Retornar um array de uma função em javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu estou tentando retornar um array de uma função para atribuir a um `model`em Angularjs. Porém o retorno da função é `undefined`, mas quando eu dou um `console.log` antes de retornar o array está correto. Como eu faço para retornar o array `clientes` e atribuir ao `model` `$scope.clientes`?

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.selected = undefined;
    $scope.clientes = getClientes($http);
    console.log(getClientes($http)); //O retorno aqui é undefined

});

function getClientes($http){
$http.get('my/url')
.then(function(response){
    var clientesJson = JSON.parse(response.data);
    var clientes = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < clientesJson['clientes'].length; i++){
        clientes.push(clientesJson['clientes'][i]['nome']);
    }
    console.log(clientes);//Aqui é mostrado o array corretamente
    return clientes;
});
```

}

Comment: E qual é o retorno da função `getClientes`? O `return` que utilizou é da função anônima passada para o `then`.

Comment: Consegui resolver colocando o `return clientes` depois do `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está fazendo é uma requisição assíncrona, então não faz sentido definir retornos, visto que você não saberá quanto tempo levará para obter o resultado - e manter seu *script* travado enquanto espera é uma péssima ideia.

Eu aconselho a você não implementar a lógica dentro da função que faz a requisição, pois isso te impedirá de utilizar a mesma requisição em partes distintas da aplicação, se necessário. O retorno da função `$http.get` é um *promise*, por isso não funciona apenas retornar um valor. O melhor, ao meu ver, seria passar uma função *callback* como parâmetro que será responsável por manipular os dados desejados:

```
function getClientes(callback) {
  $http.get('my/url')
       .then(response => {
         const json = JSON.parse(response.data)
         const nomes = json['clientes'].map(cliente => cliente['nome']);
         callback(nomes);
       })
}
```

E, por exemplo, fazer:

```
function exibeNomesClientes(nomes) {
  for (let nome of nomes) {
    console.log(nome)
  }
}

getClientes(exibeNomesClientes);
```

Desta forma, no momento que a requisição for completada, a lista de nomes dos clientes será passada como parâmetro para `exibeNomesClientes`, que exibirá no `console`, independente de quanto tempo levará para concluir a requisição, sem travar a execução do *script* na página.